# Getting 422 Status Code Error When Posting to Square?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, square-connect

Please help me finish this last step so I can be done with this project :)

I'm trying to convert this example to Vb.Net:

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/processing-payment-rest/

I can successfully get a CardOnce ID after the user enters credit card information. I can successfully do a READ from Square to get my location ID. However, I'm stuck on the last step when I provide the CardOnce ID, Location ID, and amount to POST, I keep getting back an error: "The remote server returned an error: (422) status code 422."

My Code is listed below and the error occurrs:

Error Occurs when this is called:

```
response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

Full Code Here:

```
Public Function IsSuccessProcess(ByVal sLocationId As String, ByVal sCardOnce As String, ByVal iAmount As Integer)
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader
    Dim address As Uri
    Dim data As StringBuilder
    Dim byteData() As Byte
    Dim postStream As Stream = Nothing

    address = New Uri("https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/" & sLocationId & "/transactions")

    ' Create the web request  
    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)

    ' Set type to POST  
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    request.Accept = "application/json"
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & AccessToken)

    data = New StringBuilder()
    Dim sQuote As String = """"
    sQuote = "'"
    data.Append("{" & sQuote & "card_nonce" & sQuote & ": " & sCardOnce & "," & sQuote & "amount_money" & sQuote & ": {" & sQuote & "amount" & sQuote & ": " & iAmount & "," & sQuote & "currency" & sQuote & ": " & sQuote & "USD" & sQuote & "}")

    Dim didempotency_key As Double = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Timer
    Dim idempotency_key As Integer = CInt(didempotency_key)
    data.Append("'idempotency_key': " & idempotency_key)
    ' Create a byte array of the data we want to send  
    byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString())
    ' Set the content length in the request headers  
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length

    ' Write data  
    Try
        postStream = request.GetRequestStream()
        postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    Finally
        If Not postStream Is Nothing Then postStream.Close()
    End Try

    Try
        ' Get response  
        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        ' Get the response stream into a reader  
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        ' Console application output  
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd())
    Finally
        If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
    End Try


    Return True

End Function
```

Comment: There is probably a more specific error in the body of the HTTP response - can you print that out?

Comment: I'm trying to but I'm not sure I'm looking at the right place. When I try to get a response, that's when it triggers the error, so the "response" variable is empty. I can examine parts of the "request" variable. Is there some specific variable or command I should try to look at?

Comment: I figured it out. My json string wasn't exactly right. I'll include the right version in my answer. That string is so damn temperamental :/ ... but alls well that ends well. I'd still be interested to know how to view that HTTP response, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept playing around with the JSON string and FINALLY got the winning combination. I wasn't utilizing "amount_money" correctly. Also, the SDK says you HAVE to utilize idempotency_key which I wasn't during some trials. Finally, you HAVE to use actual quotes, not a single apostrophe:

```
Dim sKey As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
Dim sMyJsonString As String
sMyJsonString = "{" & sQuote & "card_nonce" & sQuote & ":" & sQuote & sCardOnce & sQuote & "," & sQuote & "amount_money" & sQuote & ": {" & sQuote & "amount" & sQuote & ": " & iAmount & "," & sQuote & "currency" & sQuote & ": " & sQuote & "USD" & sQuote & "}," & sQuote & "idempotency_key" & sQuote & ":" & sQuote & sKey & sQuote & "}"
data.Append(sMyJsonString)
```

I finally charged $1.00 to myself that showed up in my Square account. That took a lot longer to figure out than I had hoped but All's Well that Ends Well.

Answer (score 2):

This error is likely occurring because you are using single quotes in your JSON body instead of double quotes. Try replacing those as a first step.

Note that you might find it easier to generate and parse JSON objects with the help of a third-party library such as [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Finally, as Troy mentioned, helpful error messages are returned in endpoint response bodies, which should help you diagnose future issues. See [this article](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/troubleshooting-errors/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I wish these types of questions got more visibility. I actually did try both single quote (apostrophe) and double quotes (quotes) and neither worked - in fact in my code you can see the line above the single apostrophe by default set it to double quotes which I tried first. If I have to use third-party, I will, but I'm generally reluctant to do that. I'm away from project at the moment, but I'll try to take a look and reply to Troy. Maybe I'll t ry the third party app too if it's not too difficult. Thanks again.

Comment: I figured it out. My json string wasn't exactly right. I finally found the winning combo. I'll include it in the answer.